# Next js jitter / blank moment between page transition in dev mode in Firefox

Tags: firefox, next.js

In my home page I have:

```
<Link href="/about"><a>Second page!</a></Link>
```

When I run `npm run dev` it jitters between pages (shows a blank page for a second).

[image: nextjs jitter dev recording]

When I tried to run it via [now.sh](https://now.sh) and it did transition without the jitter.
How can I fix it for my local dev environment?